# Problem connecting to socket.io and ios device on node.js (Windows)

Tags: ios, socket.io

I have a very strange problem.
I developed an ionic (capacitor) app using socket.io, I connect to a node.js desktop application. If I run the node.js application from a MacOS the iOS device is able to connect, if I run the same application on Windows the iPhone is unable to connect, I've been fighting with this problem for two days.
Thank you,
Matteo

PS: Android devices work perfectly.